# Location of BIOS file on asus eee pc 1005ha

Tags: memory, bios, eee-pc

I just upgraded ram from 1 gb to 2 gb. The system won't see the 2 gb, so I learned that I need to update the BIOS. Where is this located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a chip somewhere deep in the motherboard. - You typically use a special program to update the motherboard - it either runs within Windows or generates a disk/cd that you use on startup.

The Asus support website does not allow copy/paste direct links to certain pages (as it is all ajaxy!), so you can either [click here](http://support.asus.com/download/download.aspx?SLanguage=en-us) and navigate through the site yourself or [click here](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/EeePC/1005HA/1005HA-ASUS-1102.zip) directly for the latest (official) BIOS update.

Comment: which bios version should i user?

Comment: The latest version

Answer (score 1):

The BIOS is located on a ROM chip on your motherboard. It can be updated through a process called flashing. To find the update file, you'll need to visit your [motherboard manufacturer's website](http://support.asus.com/download/download.aspx?SLanguage=en-us) and grab it from the BIOS update section. [Uniflash](http://www.uniflash.org/) should help you with flashing it.